# 'name' field is not getting changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm making a VS CODE THEME MAKER, which returns a customised JSON (colors are given by users through input),
here's all required codebase:

```
import download from 'downloadjs';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Colin from './Colin';

interface Theme {
  name: string;
  type: string;
  colors: {
    [key: string]: string;
  };
  tokenColors: {
    scope: string[];
    settings: {
      [key: string]: string;
    };
  }[];
}

const ThemeGenerator = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<Theme>({
    name: '',
    type: "custom",
    colors: {},
    tokenColors: [],
  });

  const handleColorChange = (property: string, color: string) => {
    setTheme(prevTheme => ({
      ...prevTheme,
      colors: {
        ...prevTheme.colors,
        [property]: color,
      },
    }));
  };

  const handleNameChange = (name: string) => {
    setTheme(prevTheme => ({
      ...prevTheme,
      name: name,
    }));
  };
  
  

  const handleDownload = () => {
    const themeJSONString = JSON.stringify(theme, null, 2);
    download(themeJSONString, 'your-theme-name.json', 'application/json');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Colin handleColorChange={handleColorChange} handleNameChange={handleNameChange} />
      <button onClick={handleDownload}>Download Theme</button>
      <div>
        {/* Display the generated theme JSON */}
        <h2>Generated Theme JSON:</h2>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(theme, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ThemeGenerator;
```

and colin component is :

```
import '../colin.css';
import defaultTheme from './theme.json';

import React from 'react';

interface ColinProps {
  handleColorChange: (property: string, color: string) => void;
  setTheme: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Theme>>;
}

const Colin: React.FC<ColinProps> = ({ handleColorChange, setTheme }) => {
  const handleChange = (property: string, value: string) => {
    handleColorChange(property, value);

    // Update the theme in the ThemeGenerator component
    setTheme((prevTheme: { colors: any; }) => ({
      ...prevTheme,
      colors: {
        ...prevTheme.colors,
        [property]: value,
      },
    }));
  };





  return (
    <div className='colin'>
      <div className='colin-1'>
        <h2>Theme Name</h2>
        <input onChange={(e) => handleChange('name', e.target.value)} />
        
        <h2>Background Color</h2>
        <input onChange={(e) => handleChange('background', e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <div className='colin-1'>
        <h2>Foreground Color</h2>
        <input onChange={(e) => handleChange('foreground', e.target.value)} />
        <h2>Accent Colors</h2>
        <input onChange={(e) => handleChange('accent', e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <div className='colin-1'>
        <h2>Status Bar Colors</h2>
        <input onChange={(e) => handleChange('statusBar', e.target.value)} />
        <h2>Minimap</h2>
        <input onChange={(e) => handleChange('minimap', e.target.value)} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Colin;
```

I want the name to get changed into but
the name is getting generated inside color object instead the above name field. I've tried ChatGPT and Gemini too, but they are not able to solve this problem.

```
{
  "name": "",
  "type": "custom",
  "colors": {
    "name": "ddd",
    "foreground": "dd",
    "statusBar": "d"
  },
  "tokenColors": []
}
```

im expecting

```
{
  "name": "name here",
  "type": "custom",
  "colors": {
    
    "foreground": "dd",
    "statusBar": "d"
  },
  "tokenColors": []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Colin` Component, when you you call the `handleChange('name', e.target.value)`, it basically add the `name` key and `e.target.value` in your `color` object of your state as its value as you are calling `handleColorChange(property, value)`. You are using a wrong function (`handleColorChange`) to update the `name` key in your state.

One way to fix this would be calling the correct method (`handleNameChange`) for updating the name key !

```js
const Colin: React.FC<ColinProps> = ({ handleColorChange, setTheme, handleNameChange }) => {
  const handleChange = (property: string, value: string) => {
    handleColorChange(property, value);

    // Update the theme in the ThemeGenerator component
    setTheme((prevTheme: { colors: any; }) => ({
      ...prevTheme,
      colors: {
        ...prevTheme.colors,
        [property]: value,
      },
    }));
  };





  return (
    <div className='colin'>
      <div className='colin-1'>
        <h2>Theme Name</h2>
        <input onChange={(e) => handleNameChange(e.target.value)} />
        
        <h2>Background Color</h2>
        <input onChange={(e) => handleChange('background', e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <div className='colin-1'>
        <h2>Foreground Color</h2>
        <input onChange={(e) => handleChange('foreground', e.target.value)} />
        <h2>Accent Colors</h2>
        <input onChange={(e) => handleChange('accent', e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <div className='colin-1'>
        <h2>Status Bar Colors</h2>
        <input onChange={(e) => handleChange('statusBar', e.target.value)} />
        <h2>Minimap</h2>
        <input onChange={(e) => handleChange('minimap', e.target.value)} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Colin;
```